# How to send a command line command to put a disk in standby mode?

Tags: 20.04, disk, disk-management, standby

I want to know what is the command to put a disk in **stand by mode** by command line. My target is to make a specific script that handles the situation.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnomes-disks` relies on `udisks2`

It is possible to do the same by command line :

```
$ gdbus call --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/TOSHIBA_DT01ACA050
 --method org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata.PmStandby []
```

You might have to complete the name of your TOSHIBA disk by checking here :

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ |grep TOSHIBA
```